# Keyframing Proportional Size Parameter

Tags: animation, transforms, keyframes, proportional-editing

We want to show a scale change propagating through a model over time. Scaling a single vertex where we want the change to start from and then increasing the proportional size parameter in proportional edit mode is perfect for the effect we want, but it doesn't seem like you can directly keyframe that parameter. Is there a workaround to animating this parameter, or some other way to get the same effect that can be animated?

Comment: You can't animate a mesh in edit mode, you are effectively changing the object. You could use a latice instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use a warp modifier to do this.  A warp modifier is the live version of proportional editing:

[image]

The amount of scale is set by the difference in scale from one empty to another.  Modifier radius can be animated, acting just like increasing the radius of proportional editing.  Modifier falloff can be set as desired to match the same type of falloff you were using for editing.

[image]

Comment: This works great, just what we needed! The only thing is there isn't a connected option, but still this should work just fine for our purposes